# How to convert a EST dateformat to epoch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I need help to convert `2014-11-30T04:57:55.000-08:00` dateformat to a epoch time. Please help.

**Update**

When I use momentjs

```
var temp = "2014-11-30T04:57:55.000-08:00";
console.log(temp);
console.log(moment(temp).unix());
var d = new Date(moment(temp).unix());
console.log(d);

var translateDateWithTimeTooltip = function(value) {
    if (value == null || value == undefined)
        return value;
    var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
    var myDate = new Date( value );
    return myDate.getDate() + " " + monthNames[myDate.getMonth()] + " "+myDate.getFullYear()+ " "+myDate.getHours()+":"+myDate.getMinutes();
}
```

It gives me below result

```
2014-11-30T04:57:55.000-08:00
1417352275
17 Jan 1970 15:12
Sat Jan 17 1970 15:12:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

[Link to world time buddy](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?pl=1&lid=5,0,1275339&h=5&date=11/30/2014%7C3) IST time is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using moment, it would just be

`moment("2014-11-30T04:57:55.000-08:00").unix()`

Comment: I updated question with my try out. It's giving me `17 Jan 1970 15:12`

Comment: This answer would be a lot more helpful if you were to show the output of the steps - the final one presumably being the format the op intended?

Comment: @DannyStaple: I want the result to be in epoch time, since in my app I use this epoch time to convert it to a human readable format in few places also use this epoc time in flot chart and high charts

Comment: the unix epoch is not the same thing as javascript date objects, which use milliseconds since the epoch (not seconds).you need to add 3 zeros to the end, do so with `.valueOf()` instead of `unix()`